# System.InvalidCastException in ASP.NET MVC6 tutorial sample

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-core-mvc

I am exactly following the contents of the site http://aspnetmvc.readthedocs.org/projects/mvc/en/latest/getting-started/first-web-api.html

After copy and paste the ode, when I run the program by F5, I get below error.

Any idea what I need to do to resolve this error

> System.InvalidCastException Unable to cast object of type
>   'TodoApi.Models.TodoRepository' to type
>   'TodoApi.Models.ITodoRepository'. at
>   Microsoft.Framework.Internal.PropertyHelper.CallPropertySetter(Action setter, Object target, Object
>   value)
>
> at Microsoft.Framework.Internal.PropertyHelper.SetValue(Object
>   instance, Object value)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.DefaultControllerActionArgumentBinder.ActivateProperties(Object
>   controller, Type containerType, Dictionary properties)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.DefaultControllerActionArgumentBinder.d__4.MoveNext()
>
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>
> at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)

Comment: Edit your question add code where this error occured

Comment: Looks like your `TodoRepository` class doesn't implement the `ITodoRepository` interface, just add that.

Comment: TodoRepository  implements ITodoRepository... 

My code is copy and paste from  http://aspnetmvc.readthedocs.org/projects/mvc/en/latest/getting-started/first-web-api.html

Am I missing something else